mice: Default ridge parameter
Some methods in mice like pmm and norm apply a default ridge parameter of 1e-5 when the underlying data is nearly multi-collinear.
In van Buuren's great book chapter 6.3 (https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-modelform.html) I read that the ridge parameter could be increased to 0.001 or 0.01 to make the algorithm more robust at the expense of bias. I was wondering if there are any solid rules about the determination of theses values?
